# ADO Linq to xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am writing a prgm that via the ADO datacontext, I am running a query on the database that uses a group clase and returns an xml document.  I am able to get the xml to work, but the `XAttribute("pub_id", from p in g select new { p.Pubs_id })` is giving :

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Pubs.BookStore+BookResults,&lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType1`1[System.String]]
```

below is the code:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("reports",
 from b in bookResults 
 group b by b.Title1 into g 
 select new XElement("book", 
     new XAttribute("pub_id", from p in g select new { p.Pubs_id }), 
     new XElement("Title", g.Key), 
     from bk in g 
     select new XElement("Name", new XAttribute("au_id", bk.Au_id), bk.Name)) 
 ) 

xdoc.Save("Books.xml");
```

sample xml output desired ( using pubs sample db)

```
<reports>
  <book pub_id="1389">
    <Title>The Busy Executive's Database Guide</Title>
    <Name au_id="409-56-7008">Bennet,Abraham</Name>
    <Name au_id="213-46-8915">Green,Marjorie</Name>
  </book>
  <book pub_id="0877">
    <Title>Fifty Years in Buckingham Palace Kitchens</Title>
    <Name au_id="648-92-1872">Blotchet-Halls,Reginald</Name>
  </book>
  <book pub_id="0877">
    <Title>The Gourmet Microwave</Title>
    <Name au_id="722-51-5454">DeFrance,Michel</Name>
    <Name au_id="899-46-2035">Ringer,Anne</Name>
  </book>
```

Comment: what you said got me thinking, it seems that I need pub_id as part of the key, i did the following, and it worked

Comment: group b by new { b.Title1, b.Pubs_id } into g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're providing a query returning a sequence as the value of an attribute. My guess is that you expect there to be a single result, in which case you just need to change it to:

```
new XAttribute("pub_id", (from p in g select new { p.Pubs_id }).Single())
```

Or even:

```
new XAttribute("pub_id", (from p in g select p.Pubs_id).Single())
```

It's not really clear whether that *is* what you're expecting though - but that's the problem. LINQ to XML is calling `ToString` on your query, and you're seeing the result of that. Change the second constructor argument to something which gives a single value, however you need to do it.

I suspect you'll find that if you indent your code more clearly, it'll make it more obvious what's going on - at the moment it's not really clear just from looking at it. I would rewrite your query as provided in the question as:

```
 from b in bookResults
 group b by b.Title1 into g
 select new XElement("book",
     new XAttribute("pub_id", from p in g select new { p.Pubs_id }),
     new XElement("Title", g.Key),
     from bk in g
     select new XElement("Name", new XAttribute("au_id", bk.Au_id), bk.Name))
 )
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, by doing the above i get a debug error: sequence contains more than one element

Comment: @SKatz: Okay, so there are two or more elements... what value do you want in the attribute? It's important to understand the problem here - until you do that, you won't be able to work out the solution. The problem is you're currently trying to provide multiple values to an attribute - but an attribute only ever takes one value. I'm off to bed now, but if all of this doesn't help you, leave more details and I'll help you in the morning.

Comment: thnks, i added the xml sippet of the output

Comment: @Skatz please add updates to your question, not to answers.  Thanks!